# Html Input element, Type=File, *.flv file not a valid Mime File?

Tags: html, jquery

In the following form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="button" value="Go" />
        <input name="file" type="file" />
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(':file').on('change', function () {
                var file = this.files[0].type;
                alert('Found: ' + file);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I choose a *.flv file, I get the following Error:

```
Found: undefined
```

Even if I use:

```
var file = this.files[0].type;
alert('Found: ' + file);
```

I get:

I can only surmise the Input Element is not identifying the *.flv Mime File: `video/x-flv` as a [File Type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#video)? This is somewhat frustrating!

I have found this:

> About configuring FLV files for hosting on a server
> When you work with FLV files, you might have to configure your server to work with the FLV file format. Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) is a standardized data specification that lets you send non-ASCII files over Internet connections. Web browsers and e-mail clients are configured to interpret numerous MIME types so that they can send and receive video, audio, graphics, and formatted text. To load FLV files from a web server, you might need to register the file extension and MIME type with your web server, so you should check your web server documentation. The MIME type for FLV files is video/x-flv . The full information for the FLV file type is as follows:
>
> - Mime Type: video/x-flv
> - File extension: .flv
> - Required parameters: none
> - Optional parameters: none
> - Encoding considerations: FLV files are binary files; some applications might require the application/octet-stream subtype to be set
> - Security issues: none
> - Published specification: [www.adobe.com/go/video_file_format](http://www.adobe.com/go/video_file_format)
> - Ref: [Advanced topics for video files](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d48.html#:%7E:text=The%20MIME%20type%20for%20FLV%20files%20is%20video%2Fx%2Dflv%20.).

Using:

- Chrome: Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Edge: Version 87.0.664.52 (Official build) (64-bit)

Both are an issue?

I have gone to [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) and done the same here, using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="button" value="Go" />
        <input name="file" type="file" onchange="go(this);" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function go(element) {
    var file = element.files[0].type;
    alert('Found: ' + file);
};
```

Still have the same problem!

This code works! I get other files no problem at all!

```
Found: video/avi
Found: video/quicktime
```

Just cant find *.flv files as Mime Types? `video/x-flv`

Comment: What exactly do you think `this.files` should be pointing to?

Comment: what server are you running?

Comment: Code fixed sorry, a copy paste issue! this, is the file input type. this.files[].type is File 0.type. Second time I fixed that, wonder what happened?

Comment: @norcaljohnny - Tried on several servers, IIS, Apache, and browsers now, all the same.

Comment: can you indent your code?

Comment: @quantumPuter - Like that? It used to be the other way 10 years ago. ppl asked to remove indents.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in your code and how you are trying to get the input field's value.

You need to do

```
$('[name=file]').on('change', function () {
   var file = $(this).files[0].type;
    alert('Found: ' + file);
});
```

Also you need to wrap `this` in `$()` because it will return an array for most selectors other than id.

Comment: nope, this does not work. I updates my code as you posted. this code does not even fire the listener?

Comment: Works for me. Check your console for syntax errors why it doesn't fire.